# P(X=x|Z=z) given Z=X+Y are all rv's

Tags: probability, bayesian, random-variable, conditional-probability

Let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables where $Z=X+Y$ and $X,Y$ are independent. By Bayes' Law,
$$
\begin{align}
P(X=x|Z=z) 
&= \dfrac{P(Z=z|X=x)\ P(X=x)}{P(Z=z)}\\
&= \dfrac{P(Y=z-x)\ P(X=x)}{P(Z=z)}
\end{align}$$

such that we can compute this by just knowing the PDF of $X$ and $Y$. This is because $P(Z=z)$ can be found by computing their convolution.

However, when I see that I used $P(Z=z|X=x)=P(Y=z-x)$ in going from the first line to the second, it makes me think that I could have just used $P(X=x|Z=z)=P(Y=z-x)$ initially. Clearly that's incorrect because it doesn't match up with the formula above, but I can't figure out why. Can anyone intuitively (or mathematically) show why $P(X=x|Z=z)\neq P(Y=z-x)$ when $Z=X+Y$?

Comment: Your assertion that $P(Z=z\mid X=x)=P(Y=z−x)$ is not always true.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then it's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can use convolution for $P(Z=z)$ only when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. You're actually implementing that independence when you say

$P(Z=z|X=x)=P(Y+X=z|X=x)=P(Y=z-X|X=x)=P(Y=z-x|X=x)=P(Y=z-x)$.

But, you cannot do that in LHS since $Y$ and $Z$ are not independent.

$P(X=x|Z=z)=P(Z-Y=x|Z=z)=P(Y=z-x|Z=z)\neq P(Y=z-x)$

Comment: X and Y are independent. I'll edit my post to clarify. Thanks!